# Android emulator blank on "newer" AVDs, even after several hours, on decent machine w/HAXM

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, haxm, android-studio-2.0

Setup: Win7/64 with Android Studio 1.4 and also with 2.0 Preview 5 on the same machine (i5-2450M w/4 GB, HAXM 6.0.1 supported and set at 2 GB).

I have not tried exhaustively, but on the handful of AVD combinations I have tried, I can only get AVDs running Android 2.2 ("Froyo", arm, API 8) to actually boot (takes a few minutes and is slow, but works).

Anything newer (from API 15-23; on API 15 I've tried both ARM and x86 Atom) shows the emulator window but never shows anything inside the phone's screen besides blackness, even if left for up to 14 hours.

I know there are other emulators out there, but I am wondering why, on a fairly decent setup, this isn't working.

Android Studio's output window says this, fairly quickly, and then never anything thereafter:

```
emulator.exe -avd Nexus_5_API_15
emulator: device fd:516
HAXM is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
emulator: UpdateChecker: skipped version check
```

If i try to run an app anyway, it says:

```
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com....."
Error: Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?
```

From then on (even hours later, and whether I tell AS to install my app or not) emulator-x86.exe takes 848 MB of RAM, and CPU varies 0-25, although usually 0.

AVD details are as follows:

```
Name: Nexus_5_API_15
CPU/ABI: Intel Atom (x86)
Path: ...\.android\avd\Nexus_5_API_15.avd
Target: Android API 15 (API level 15)
Skin: 1080x1920
SD Card: ...\.android\avd\Nexus_5_API_15.avd\sdcard.img
Snapshot: true
hw.lcd.density: 480
hw.dPad: no
avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8
hw.camera.back: none
disk.dataPartition.size: 300M
skin.dynamic: yes
hw.keyboard: yes
hw.device.hash2: MD5:2fa0e16c8cceb7d385183284107c0c88
hw.ramSize: 768
tag.id: default
tag.display: Default
hw.sdCard: yes
hw.device.manufacturer: Google
hw.mainKeys: no
hw.accelerometer: yes
hw.trackBall: no
hw.device.name: Nexus 5
hw.sensors.proximity: yes
hw.battery: yes
hw.sensors.orientation: yes
hw.audioInput: yes
hw.camera.front: none
hw.gps: yes
snapshot.present: true
vm.heapSize: 64
```

I'm not looking for a "just use Genymotion" answer, but a reason why this might occur without giving any actual indication of a boot problem in the output.

**Update**

Running `logcat` shows [this](http://pastebin.com/8Ee3GFjU).  Whenever it got to a line saying `Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...` it would wait a few seconds and then output more, eventually pausing at the next `Waiting for service SurfaceFlinger...`.  25 MB of this output, and counting...

Comment: What does logcat says? I've experienced similar problem in our office and even Genymotion had same problem. In the first few days emulator worked fine but suddenly become not working. We tried various trouble shooting, but in the end, emulator recovered by simply changing the windows theme. And we still don't know what really caused the such behavior.

Comment: @FrozenFire, thanks, I've updated to include part of the output (it's too big for pastebin, but seems to loop before that point.)

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing the emulator `/data` partition (Wipe User Data option available in the AVD Manager).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's the part that always occurs just after those lines:

```
E/FramebufferNativeWindow( ....): couldn't open framebuffer HAL (No such file or directory)
```

[This thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-building/-kGT71_fDGg) (with JBQ, no less!) suggests that a) it is Nexus-specific and b) that it was fixed in some context or other.

b) does not appear to apply to my particular context, obviously, otherwise it would work with the Nexus, too.

However, a) seems to be accurate: if I make an AVD with the same Intel Atom x86 API 15 platform, but with a generic 5.1" WGVA device instead of the Nexus 5, it shows the Android logo on the emulator.  With 512 MB in the AVD setup it does not seem to boot, but with 768 it boots within seconds from scratch...very nice!